# Is there a way to mark a property as immutable in Terraform resource?

Tags: terraform

There're 2 properties for my terraform resource and one of them can be updated but the other can't so I want to mark it as immutable but when I open https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/blob/main/helper/schema/schema.go#L37, it seems like there's no such an option.

Can I mark a property as immutable in Terraform resource anyhow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question I think you are asking about a provider you are developing, rather than a Terraform module written against an existing provider.

Lots of remote APIs have object properties that are fixed once the object is created, but preventing them from changing altogether would violate Terraform's declarative model, and so the typical way to represent this in providers is for the provider to respond to a change on such an attribute by reporting that it can't make that change without replacing the object, which is to say: destroying the existing object and creating a new one to replace it.

In the Terraform SDK there's a convenient attribute for the common case that *any* value change requires replacement: if you set `ForceNew: true` then the SDK will automatically notice if there's a change to the value of that attribute and report back to Terraform that the change is impossible without replacing the object. Terraform will then ask the provider to plan to create a new object instead, and present the result to the user as a planned action where the resource instance "must be replaced", with an annotation attached to the argument whose change prompted that proposal.

In some rarer cases the rules are more complicated, such as it being possible to change values in *certain* ways but not in other ways. For example, if a resource type is representing a virtual disk then it might be possible to *grow* the disk without replacing it, but not possible to *shrink* it. In that case, you can use the resource-level `CustomizeDiff` function to specify some custom logic for making the decision, calling `ResourceDiff.ForceNew` conditionally if e.g. the change to the disk size indicates that the new value is less than the old value.

You can think of the `ForceNew: true` attribute-level setting as a convenience shorthand for the more general `CustomizeDiff` approach, which suffices for most common situations.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean an attribute, let's say I want to ignore changes to tags in a resource, then use

```
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      # Ignore changes to tags, e.g. because a management agent
      # updates these based on some ruleset managed elsewhere.
      tags,
    ]
  }
```